# Maximum number of rows limit on Bigtable

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

I have a requirement to store around ~10 billion rows at Big Table. Data Might grow to ~100 billion in future.

I tried to find the maximum info in the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/quotas#:%7E:text=A%20single%20row%20key%3A%204,a%20table%20cell%3A%2010%20MB), but there is no such mention of the maximum amount of rows Bigtable can have. The data size of each row would be around 1 KB

Answer (score 2):

As per the [Documentation-1](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/overview),

> Cloud Bigtable is a sparsely populated table that can scale to billions of rows and thousands of columns.

About the limitation [Cloud Bigtable Rows](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design-time-series#rows-not-infinite) can be big but are not infinite, the rows can contain ~100 column families and millions of columns but the recommendation is 100MB for row size.

In BigTable, the limit of the data within a table is based on data size instead of the number of columns or rows (except for "Column families per table"). Therefore you need to make sure the row size should be within the hard limit as stated in the [Documentation-2](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/quotas#limits-data-size),

> As a best practice, [design your schema](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design) to keep the size of your data within the recommended limits in the Documentation.

Answer (score 0):

100 billion rows x 1 KB/row = 100 TB of storage.

For SSD storage, the Bigtable limit is 5 TB per node [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/quotas#storage-per-node) but the design goal is 70% storage utilization [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/monitoring-instance#disk) so you need (100 / (5 * .70)) = 28 nodes.

The default BigTable node limit is 200 nodes for us-central1. [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/quotas#nodes-per-project)

Google Bigtable supports petabytes of storage. Based upon the information in your question, Bigtable will support your requirement of 100 billion rows of 1 KB per row.