# JAVA GCP Bigtable Max Multiple Reads At Once

Tags: java, google-cloud-bigtable

I am trying to query bigTable and in a sense do bulk reads. GCP has the following code that allows you to query multiple records from bigtable. My question is what is the max allowed number of rowKeys that I can append to this query? Currently there are 2, can I query 10,000 or 100,000 rowkeys with this query?

`Query.create(tableId).rowKey("phone#4c410523#20190501").rowKey("phone#4c410523#20190502");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the maximum number of rowKeys that can be included in a single query is 10,000 .

so it is better to keep follow the best practice only.

for reference you may like to go through: [schema-design#tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design#tables)

also be useful to read: [maximum-number-of-rows-limit-on-bigtable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76277676/maximum-number-of-rows-limit-on-bigtable)